# enable ssh over virtual machines running on kvm

Tags: ssh, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to connect to a virtual machine running on KVM hypervisor from a host machine (Ubuntu 14.04) through ssh, but it is giving me the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.117.82.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

How can I enable `ssh` on the guest virtual machine? I've installed the virtual machine using `virt-install`. So, is there any provision in `virt-install` for enabling `ssh`?

Comment: You install and enable it the same as any other system.

Comment: okay, but specifically is there any provision in the virt-install utility to enable ssh during virtual machine installation?

Comment: virt-install just runs the operating system installer. It's up to you to preseed/kickstart that if you wish. Remember that Debian/Ubuntu do _not_ install an ssh server by default.

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way to apply the initial configurations such as SSH installation is to use VNC.

1. Use the following command to get the list of VMs

`sudo virsh list --all`

2. Open the XML config file:

`sudo virsh edit YOUR_VM_NAME`

3. Append the following line before final :

> ```
> <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='192.168.1.5' passwd='YOUR-PASSWORD-HERE' keymap='en-us'/>
> ```

where the listen address is the IP address of the server, not the guest OS

4. Use a VNC client to connect to the guest OS